# how to remove '+' in scientific mode output

Tags: c++, io, cout

I have this code:

```cpp
std::cout << std::scientific << 1e9;
```

It outputs `1.000000e+09` but I don't want the `+`.

I tried using `std::showpos` , it doesn't work for that.

I thought about writing an output function specifically, but I'd prefer to find an easier way.

Comment: `std::ostringstream ss; ss << std::scientific << 1e9; std::string s = ss.str(); s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '+'), s.end(); std::cout << s;`

Comment: @Eljay This works (but you missed a `)` after `end()`)

Comment: I would hope that reading about `std::showpos` would show why it would have never worked.

Comment: Sorry about that, I typed it on the fly.